# How map objects to a view with EF 4 code first?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef4-code-only

How can you map an entity to a database view with EF 4 code first?

Is there a way to do this by deriving from the EntityConfiguration classes?

Comment: Can you futher explain your question? What is the view? Is it entity? If not how it differs from entity?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes!
I found the answer:

> You can certainly use Code First to
>   map to a view, just tell Code First
>   that it's a table and it will use the
>   same SQL against the view that it
>   would for a table. Obviously if your
>   view isn't writeable then saving is
>   going to fail if you try and update
>   values in the entities that are based
>   on the view, but we will just delegate
>   to the database so if you don't update
>   these entities then you won't have any
>   issues.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/f154595c-717e-4703-a81d-ee63633a481e

Comment: Nice I didn't know about that but still it is a hack not a feature.

Comment: Is it really a hack? How do you distinguish between a view and a table when writing standard TSQL

Comment: @mjmcloug There is some hackery here. If we have EF create the DB, how do we tell it not to create the table? I'm resorting to creating a table the dropping it and creating a view when seeding.

Comment: Sorry @ProfK I don't use EF to create the database so can't help you on that one.

Comment: Presumably, if you're trying to map a model to a view, you're talking about an existing database. Although "code first" may be a confusing name when talking about existing database, you can use it with an existing database.

Comment: I like calling Code First with an Existing Database "Code Second"

Comment: "you're talking about an existing database" What about a view created to work around a EF6 incapability with multiple projections and union?