# Is it possible to add a view in code-first context?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to map an entity to a database view using code-first?

Comment: How is it code first then?  Or do you mean using the dbcontext api?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How map objects to a view with EF 4 code first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595786/how-map-objects-to-a-view-with-ef-4-code-first)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham, as you can see I often mark some answers as useful then tag it as answer if it's really my accepted answer, but on some cases it really is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a view, an alternative is to call a stored procedure using the DbContext class.

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<Model>("spTest").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You have to construct the View manually however. This can be done using a custom database initializer. Then you can just map an entity to a view since the underlying SQL syntax is the same. See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/f154595c-717e-4703-a81d-ee63633a481e

**EDIT** as  Merlyn Morgan-Graham points out, this is a duplicate to [Is it possible to add a view in code-first context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975870/is-it-possible-to-add-a-view-in-code-first-context)