# How to create a view using EF code-first POCO

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

That simple. I need to create a **View** using Code First. I found nothing about this on google nor SO. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I need that view to be created and queried using linq, so it's not a solution to create it using an script on Database creation, for example:

```
var results = from c in db.Customer
join v in db.MyView on c.Id equals v.Id
select c;
```

A work around is also acceptable. I need a way to query entities against non-constant/ non-entities values.

Comment: create a view: create an sql view, just like you code an entity and it's translated as a Table on SQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot create views with EF Code First approach. If you want to create view then execute creation sql script in `Seed` method. But you'll still not be able to map entity to this view, except hacking model by creating and droping table with same name as your view will have.

Some helpful links:

- [How map objects to a view with EF 4 code first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595786/how-map-objects-to-a-view-with-ef-4-code-first)
- [How do I define a database view using Entity Framework 4 Code-First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889905/how-do-i-define-a-database-view-using-entity-framework-4-code-first)

Comment: This was an unimaginative answer. Workarounds were probably possible back in 2012. Make sure you look at the other answers.

Comment: SqlGenerator w/ Table Annotations anyone? strange answer.

Comment: What is "the seed method"?

Answer (score 95):

you must manually create the view, just like AnatoliiG stated. ([Adding index to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040795/adding-index-to-a-table/5041221#5041221)).

You add the name of the view as an attribute to your class

```
[Table("UserDTO")]
    public class UserDTO
{
    /* Class code here */
}
```

You can create an empty migration by specifying the -IgnoreChanges attribute at the end

```
Add-Migration MigrationName -IgnoreChanges
```

This gives you an empty migration script that you can manually modify.

You can use your db context to execute your code in your migration script

```
public partial class editUserDTO : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        string script =
        @"
        CREATE VIEW dbo.UserDTO
        AS SELECT p.PersonId AS UserId, p.FirstName, p.LastName, u.UserName
        FROM dbo.Users u
        INNER JOIN dbo.People p ON u.PersonId = p.PersonId";
        BloggingContext ctx = new BloggingContext();
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        BloggingContext ctx = new BloggingContext();
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DROP VIEW dbo.UserDTO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `CREATE` only should be in  `Up()` and the `DROP` only be in the `Down()`?

Comment: hi there... Attempted to correct the code I wrote in this post, (removed ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script); from the "Down" method) but was rejected by 3 users.

Comment: how to map my existing sql server to EF code first ? looking for good example. thanks

Comment: I did this and I get an error "Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled."  How do you resolve this?

Comment: Instead of creating a context and calling `ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`, you can just use the `Sql(...)` function inherited from `DbMigration`.

Comment: Won't the changes ignored by `-IgnoreChanges` show up in the next added migration?

Comment: Maybe missings steps, but I had to add Dbset of the new view class to the DbContext before the "Add-Migration" step.   Also, after editing the empty migration script to implement the add and drop of the view, I had to drop the view manually and the run "Update-Database" to make sure I didn't make a mistake in the script and to complete the migration/database-update pair.

Answer (score 22):

Just a heads up, in EF 6.1 (not sure if in earlier or not) there is now a `Code First from Database` option you can use and it will map to views as well.

I personally have mine in a separate junk project so I can just take out the code I want from it and not impact my project that actually uses the database. To use it `Add a New file to your project -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model`

Then select the `Code First From Database` option and select your views (and other tables if you want)

It will create it as a Table mapping like Fred was talking about in his answer, but will do all the code for you which is nice. You'll probably want to change the indexes and ordering though.

Then just call `Sql(@"YOUR VIEW CREATE SQL HERE")` in your `Up` and add a `Sql(@"DROP STATEMENT HERE")` in your `Down`

Answer (score 22):

A lot of good insights from the [official issues thread of EF7](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4561):

1) **Don't have a DbSet, and instead have a property or extension method**

A) Property

```
class YourContext
{
    public IQueryable<YourView> YourView 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Database.SqlQuery<YourView>("select * from dbo.YourView");
        }
    }
}
```

B) Extension Method

```
static class YourContextExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<YourView>(this YourContext context)
    {
        return context.Database.SqlQuery<YourView>("select * from dbo.YourView");
    }
```

2) **Apparently, you can have the migration process ignore certain dbsets**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  if (IsMigration)
    modelBuilder.Ignore<YourViewTable>();
 ...
}
```

(All the above are untested)

Comment: A point doesn't work `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Syste.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery .. to ...<model>` you must change IQueryable to IEnumerable

Comment: Tack, asqueryable to the end after sqlquery function

Comment: No, don't chain `AsQueryable` after `SqlQuery`. That won't provide you with a dynamic query object. When using `SqlQuery` as suggested, all records will be selected and loaded into memory, even though the code filters them with a `Where` or uses `FirstOrDefault`... See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28664167/1185136).

Comment: Solution number 2 tested and working here. I have used https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102959/1291428 as an inspiration for setting the isMigration flag.

Comment: @Todd B cannot compile, where did you manage to get "this" in a static class without being in the method signature? =]

Comment: @Ethouarn fixed

Answer (score -5):

You cannot create a view from EF Code First ,you should add the script in the 'seed' script to pre populate the view .

Comment: Hi! Please revise your answer as it doesn't actually answer the OP's question but instead just indicates that what the OP wants to do can't be done. If you need help, check out [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help section.

Comment: I don't think this belongs in the seed method. Creating a view should be done in an EF migration.

Comment: This answer is the same as [this one from four years previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13594252/215552).