# How do you configure the DbContext when creating Migrations in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Is there way that dependency injection can be configured/bootstrapped when using Entity Framework's migration commands?

Entity Framework Core supports dependency injection for `DbContext` subclasses.  This mechanism includes allowing for configuration of data access outside of of the `DbContext`.

For example, the following would configure EF to persist to a SQL server using a connection string retrieved from `config.json`

```
ServiceCollection services = ...

var configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile( "config.json" );
services.AddEntityFramework( configuration )
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<BillingDbContext>( config => config.UseSqlServer() );
```

However, the migrations commands do not know to execute this code so `Add-Migration` will fail for lack of a provider or lack of a connection string.

Migrations can be made to work by overriding `OnConfiguring` within the `DbContext` subclass to specify the provider and configuration string, but that gets in the way when different configuration is desired elsewhere.  Ultimately keeping my the migration commands and my code both working becomes undesirably complex.

Note: My `DbContext` lives in a different assembly than the entry point that uses it and my solution has multiple start-up projects.

Comment: Figuring this out is part of issue [#639](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/639). In ASP.NET 5, we'll call `Startup.ConfigureServices()`. In your opinion, would it be good to use the same convention for non-ASP.NET 5 projects?

Comment: @bricelam Now that I have done some development in ASP.NET 5 (was using EF7 in traditional .NET application) I can say standardizing around the `Startup` class sounds good to me.

Comment: I pushed for it in [aspnet/Hosting#286](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/286), but lost. The decision was to have different DbContext loaders for different application types. See [aspnet/EntityFramework#2357](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2357).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@bricelam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475031/bricelam) commented this functionality does not yet exist in Entity Framework 7.  This missing functionality is tracked by GitHub issue [aspnet/EntityFramework#639](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/639)

In the mean time, the easier workaround I found was to utilize a global state rather than hassle with subclassing.  Not usually my first design choice but it works well for now.

In MyDbContext:

```
public static bool isMigration = true;

protected override void OnConfiguring( DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder )
{
    // TODO: This is messy, but needed for migrations.
    // See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/639
    if ( isMigration )
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer( "<Your Connection String Here>" );
    }
}
```

In `Startup.ConfigureServices()`.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    MyContext.isMigration = false;

    var configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile( "config.json" );
    services.AddEntityFramework( configuration )
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>( config => config.UseSqlServer() );
    // ...
}
```

(The configuration code actually lives in an Autofac Module in my case.)

Comment: You may check optionsBuilder.IsConfigured property instead of the isMigration flag.

Answer (score 26):

If you are looking for a solution to configure context for migrations, you can use this in your `DBContext` class:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DbCoreConnectionString");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
    }
```

Remember to install those two packages to have `SetBasePath` and `AddJsonFile` methods:
`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`

`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

Answer (score 8):

#### Use [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-2.1)

If a class implementing this interface is found in either the same project as the derived `DbContext` or in the application's startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the `DbContext` and use the design-time factory instead.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class BloggingContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
    {
        public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

            return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

applied in Entity Framework 2.0, 2.1

---

**Using `IDbContextFactory<TContext>`**  is now [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.idbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-2.1).

<s>Implement this interface to enable design-time services for context types that do not have a public default constructor. Design-time services will automatically discover implementations of this interface that are in the same assembly as the derived context.</s>

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class BloggingContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
    {
        public BloggingContext Create()
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connection_string");

            return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

more info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

If you're not happy with the hard-coded connection-string, take a look at [this](https://www.benday.com/2017/02/17/ef-core-migrations-without-hard-coding-a-connection-string-using-idbcontextfactory/) article.

Comment: This class is obsolete now.

Comment: Your updated solution is exactly the same as @Anton's. It should be reverted to its older state and kept for historical purposes.

Comment: Note that `IDbContextFactory<>` was moved to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace in efcore 5 and is no longer obsolete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.idbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-5.0

Answer (score 4):

In .NET Core since version 2.1 should be used `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` because `IDbContextFactory` is obsolete.

```cs
public class FooDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<FooDbContext>
{
    public FooDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FooDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringName");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new FooDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To combine the answers above this works for me

```
private readonly bool isMigration = false;
public MyContext()
{
    isMigration = true;
}

public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
{

}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (isMigration)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("CONNECTION_STRING");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but I use the onConfiguring method and I don't have this problem

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Startup.Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro, unless something has changed, this does not work out in my situation.  The `Startup` class my application uses cannot be referenced in the `DbContext` subclass because they live in different assemblies.  Doing this configuration here and in `Startup` is not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 'Migration' folder from another assembly in the same solution then you could use this:

```
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<VSContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString, x => x.MigrationsAssembly("VS.Infrastructure.DAL"));
        });
```

If helped please UpVote as I trying to earn points - Thank you

More detailed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0):

I just ask for an instance and run migrations in my Startup.cs file

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ASPNet Core Identity
        services.AddDbContext<RRIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RRIdentityConnectionString")));

     }
```

And then in Configure:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var rrIdentityContext = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RRIdentityDbContext>();
        rrIdentityContext.Database.Migrate();
    }
```

Note: There is no 'EnsureCreated' for the database. Migrate is supposed to create it if it doesn't exist, although how it is supposed to figure out the permissions I don't know - so I created an empty database.

Comment: Thank you. In my scenario I have a `DbContext` with custom configuration in the `OnConfiguring` method, and I want it do generate multiple databases, so I need to call `context.Database.Migrate` post context configuration. Where is the right place to do that?