# Mapping View To MVC Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, sql-view

I have view in SQL called **ViewTest**.

[image]

In code I have this model

```
    [Table("dbo.ViewTest")]
    public class ViewTest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string PreferredName { get; set; }
        public string EmailPrimaryWork { get; set; }
        public string GeoCoverage { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public bool? LeftEmpFlag { get; set; }
    }
```

In configuration file:

```
public virtual IDbSet<ViewTest> ViewTests { get; set; }


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ViewConfiguration());
        }

 public class ViewConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ViewTest>
        {
            public ViewConfiguration()
            {
                this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
                this.ToTable("ViewTest");
            }
        }
```

I want to have connection like this one ViewTests.Where(....) ,but when I tried to do like this way I have error **There is already an object named 'ViewTest' in the database.**.This means entity framework try to create new Table and I don`t want this.I want to access this view only!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is code first so you should probably [create your view in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593845/how-to-create-a-view-using-ef-code-first-poco). If that is not possible, then you need to tell EF not to create the table by commenting that line out of the Up() method on the migration. Once you update-database EF will have it in the metadata and you should be good to go.