# inquiry about DbContext

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

I am using database first approach ,when i create **Module1 **that have my database structure ,whene I need to create my database againe by using this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim createdb As New Model1
        createdb.Database.Create()
    End Sub
```

its create databse and tables corectly,but Views in my organal database converts th tables.
Can anyone help me to avoid that

I want to reflect my database with all its structures "tables,vwies,functions,,, and so on. with using vb.net EF

Answer (score 0):

If you're recreating a DB using code-first to mirror the original DB, then you cannot [create views without some effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593845/how-to-create-a-view-using-ef-code-first-poco)

What you really want to do is [create the code equivalent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/) of your DB using a tool, in this case EF Designer that comes with Visual Studio. You have to create the model (ie the code representing the DB) and then the views as a separate step.